# Sass @use and the style.css file header

Tags: css, import, sass

Apologies if this has already been asked/answered, but numerous searches haven't turned up what I'm looking for.

I've been out of the dev game for a minute and I came back to see that Sass is warning folks off of using @import. I'd just started to pick up Sass before my hiatus so maybe I'm trying to do this wrong but...

Let's say I have a style.scss:

```
/*!
 * Theme name
 * Etc...
*/
@import 'partial..';
```

The styles go right where I want them to - where they're called. But if I @use...

```
/*!
 * Theme name
 * Etc...
*/
@use 'partial..';
```

I end up with this in my style.css:

```
[[[ Styles from @use(s) 
...
...
...]]]
/*!
 * Theme name
 * Etc...
*/
[[[ Styles I've left on @import ]]]
[[[ Other styles ]]]
```

Is there a way to pin the output of @use so it's below the file header, am I missing some piece of logic/doing this wrong, or is this just something that we'll have to cope with once @import goes the way of the dodo?